# Decidability of completeness in propositional logic

Tags: lo.logic, decidability

Propositional logic can be presented as in Mendelson’s book, with the sole inference rule of modus ponens, and with the following three axioms:
$$B \Rightarrow (C \Rightarrow B)$$
$$(B \Rightarrow (C \Rightarrow D)) \Rightarrow ((B \Rightarrow C) \Rightarrow (B \Rightarrow D))$$
$$((\neg C) \Rightarrow (\neg B)) \Rightarrow (((\neg C) \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow C)$$
This is a sound and complete theory, as are several other theories for propositional logic.

I have questions about similar theories for propositional logic:

1. Given a complete set of logical connectives and a finite set of sound axioms and inference rules, can we algorithmically determine if the resulting theory is complete?
2. Given a finite set of axioms and inference rules $X$ (not necessarily sound) and a formula $\alpha$ in the underlying language of propositional connectives, can we algorithmically determine if $\alpha$ can be derived from $X$?

Comment: @MattF. I wish to allow arbitrary substitutions of formulas in for the variables (which means there are say infinitely many proofs of a given length).  In the case of say $L$ above, this would always yield tautologies, whereas with an arbitrary $X$, we will just get a whole bunch of formulas (many of which are not tautologies if the original axioms/inference rules aren't sound).

Comment: This question seems most interesting for logics with infinitely many distinct sentences — like intuitionist propositional logic with the Rieger-Nishimura lattice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Syntax

Comment: Q2 is undecidable, as one can take for $X$ an axiomatization of an undecidable propositional logic such as one of the relevance logics considered by [Urquhart: The undecidability of entailment and relevant implication](https://doi.org/10.2307/2274261). Q1 is most likely undecidable as well, but this requires a different argument.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thank you - that reference is very helpful!  Do you happen to know if any of these undecidable propositional logics every have the property that for a fixed formula $A$ and positive integer $k$, we can determine if there is a proof of $A$ in $k$ steps?

Comment: This is decidable (in NP, if $k$ is given in unary) for *all* propositional logics axiomatized by finitely many schematic rules and axioms. For a given $k$, there are only finitely many proof skeletons (i.e., directed acyclic graphs with labels indicating for each node from which nodes it is derived and what rule is used) of size $k$, and you can enumerate them algorithmically. For a fixed skeleton, an assignment of formulas to nodes that makes a valid derivation is a first-order syntactic unification problem; thus, we can determine in polynomial time whether it has a solution, and if so, ...

Comment: ... compute the most general unifier. Then any other valid proof with the given skeleton is a substitution instance of the mgu, thus it suffices to check (in polynomial time) whether the target formula is a substitution instance of the end-formula of the mgu.

Comment: (The computed mgu will have formulas represented as circuits, i.e., directed acyclic graphs rather than trees.) An alternative way to phrase the unification argument is as follows: if $A$ has a proof with $k$ steps, it has a proof with $k$ steps in which all formulas have circuit size polynomial in $k$ and $|A|$ (hence the whole proof can be represented by a polynomial-size object). A direct proof of this is given e.g. in Lemma 4.4.4 of Krajíček, Bounded arithmetic, propositional logic, and proof complexity (where it is formulated in terms of formula depth rather than circuit size).

Comment: It was shown already by Post and Linial that the question whether a set of propositional formulae together with the rule of modus ponens axiomatizes exactly the classical propositional logic is algorithmically undecidable.

Comment: @KarelChvalovský Ahoj Karle, that’s great. Since it completely answers the question, can you post it as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Ahoj Emile, done :)

Comment: Thank you all - this has been very informative for me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is undecidable, because it is even undecidable to recognize whether a finite set of axioms together with the rule of modus ponens axiomatizes exactly classical propositional logic by the Post-Linial theorem. This was shown in 1948 by Linial and Post, see their [announcement (p. 50)](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-01/S0002-9904-1949-09162-0/S0002-9904-1949-09162-0.pdf), but the first published [proof](https://doi.org/10.1305/ndjfl/1093957737) is by Yntema. There are many similar results for other propositional logics.